# Parsec try : should try to go to next option

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

Currently, I have the following code:

```hs
import Control.Applicative ((<|>))
import Text.Parsec (ParseError, endBy, sepBy, try)
import Text.Parsec.String (Parser)
import qualified Data.Char as Char
import qualified Text.Parsec as Parsec

data Operation = Lt | Gt deriving (Show)

data Value =
      Raw String
    | Op Operation
  deriving (Show)

sampleStr :: String
sampleStr =  unlines
  [ "#BEGIN#"
  , "x <- 3.14 + 2.72;"
  , "x < 10;"
  ]

gtParser :: Parser Value
gtParser = do
  Parsec.string "<"
  return $ Op Gt

ltParser :: Parser Value
ltParser = do
  Parsec.string ">"
  return $ Op Lt

opParser :: Parser Value
opParser = gtParser <|> ltParser

rawParser :: Parser Value
rawParser = do
  str <- Parsec.many1 $ Parsec.satisfy $ not . Char.isSpace
  return $ Raw str

valueParser :: Parser Value
valueParser = try opParser <|> rawParser

eolParser :: Parser Char
eolParser = try (Parsec.char ';' >> Parsec.endOfLine)
         <|> Parsec.endOfLine

lineParser :: Parser [Value]
lineParser = sepBy valueParser $ Parsec.many1 $ Parsec.char ' '

fileParser :: Parser [[Value]]
fileParser = endBy lineParser eolParser

parse :: String -> Either ParseError [[Value]]
parse = Parsec.parse fileParser "fail..."

main :: IO ()
main = print $ parse sampleStr
```

This will fail with the message

```
Left "fail..." (line 2, column 4):
unexpected "-"
expecting " ", ";" or new-line
```

To my understanding, since I have `try opParser`, after Parsec sees that the token `<-` cannot be parsed by `opParser`, it should go to `rawParser`. (It is essentially a lookahead).

What is my misunderstanding, and how do I fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replicate the problem with the smaller test case:

```
> Parsec.parse fileParser "foo" "x <- 3.14"
```

The problem is that `fileParser` first calls `lineParser`, which successfully parses `"x <"` into `[Raw "x", Op Gt]` and leaves `"- 3.14"` yet to be parsed.  Unfortunately, `fileParser` now expects to parse something with `eolParser`, but `eolParser` can't parse `"- 3.14"` because it starts with neither a semicolon nor an `endOfLine`.

Your `try opParser` has no effect here because `opParser` successfully parses `<`, so there's nothing to backtrack from.

There are many ways you might fix the problem.  If `<-` is the only case where a `<` might be misparsed, you could exclude this case with `notFollowedBy`:

```
gtParser :: Parser Value
gtParser = do
  Parsec.string "<"
  notFollowedBy $ Parsec.string "-"
  return $ Op Gt
```

Comment: Shouldn't lineParser parse the entire line, "x <- 3.14" in this case?

Comment: It seems that you want `fileParser` to produce something like `[[Raw "x", Op Gt, Raw "-",Raw "3.14",Raw "+",Raw "2.72"], ...]`. It cannot do this because it applies `valueParser` to parse `<`, then `sepBy` is trying to parse 1 or more space characters, but the next character is `-`, so `sepBy` ends, and so the entire `lineParser` ends. The remaining input is `- 3.14 + 2.72;\n <...>` which fails for `eolParser` (clearly `-` is not a newline nor `;` followed by a newline).

Comment: If you want a parser which eats up the rest of the line as a `Raw` if there's any sort of failure in `lineParser`, you can try e.g. `(\xs x -> xs ++ [x]) <$> lineParser <*> (Raw <$> Parsec.many (Parsec.satisfy (\c -> not (c \`elem\` ";\n"))))`